# Framework7 Built-in AJAX doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-cordova, html-framework-7

I wanted to load the login page as soon as the the connection to the database has been made but FW7's ajax doesn't work.

```
myApp.onPageInit('splash-screen', function (page) {
myApp.alert("LOADED");
$$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.8:80/saklolo-php/dbconfig.php",
    successs: function (data, result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            if (data != "error") {
                mainView.router.loadPage('login.html');
            } else {
                myApp.alert("Please check your network connection..");
            }
        } else {
            myApp.alert(result);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, error) {
        myApp.alert("Status: " + jqXHR.status);
        myApp.alert(error);
    }
});
```

});

How do I know that the AJAX doesn't work? Well the alert on top of it works so the page has initialized but the ajax doesn't work, I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Does `http://192.168.1.8:80/saklolo-php/dbconfig.php` work?

Comment: I've no idea actually :/ That's my current lan IP and I think that's how it works when you are going to connect to localhost.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: Yea, it works. Just tried it.

Comment: Any errors on the Javascript console?

Comment: Perhaps `$$` should be `$`

Comment: Nah, $ is jquery, I'm using framework7. The only error is "Debugger agent is not enabled".

Comment: I have not used framework7. But bung in a few `console.log...` to find out what is happening

Comment: I already did put a lot of consoles but doesn't seem to bring out the problem. :/

Comment: With those log messages is `successs` function being called?

Comment: It's not being called, neither of them is being called

Comment: Why not just use JQuery?

Comment: I can use Jquery but I don't think it's wise :S I'll try tho.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code by http://jsfiddle.net so we can help?